# Find word in file - if file contains will output path to console

Tags: java, file, search

I need to create a program, which does a few things:

- takes parameters: word to find and a path to look
- looking for the given word at files one by one
- If the word has found in the file -> print to console `filename` - `file path`

Traverse all folders with the same parsing algorithm till it will be possible.

Here is code snipped:

```
class SearchPhrase {
    // walk to root way
    public void walk(String path, String whatFind) throws IOException {
        File root = new File(path);
        File[] list = root.listFiles();
        for (File titleName : list) {
            if (titleName.isDirectory()) {
                walk(titleName.getAbsolutePath(), whatFind);
            } else {
                if (read(titleName.getName()).contains(whatFind)) {
                    System.out.println("File: " + titleName.getAbsoluteFile());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Read file as one line
    public static String read(String fileName) {
        StringBuilder strBuider = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName).getAbsoluteFile()));
            String strInput;
            while ((strInput = in.readLine()) != null) {
                strBuider.append(strInput);
                strBuider.append("\n");
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strBuider.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SearchPhrase example = new SearchPhrase();
        try {
            example.walk("C:\\Documents and Settings\\User\\Java", "programm");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Program doesn't compil with following errors:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\User\Java Hangman\Java\Anton\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs 
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
    at task.SearchPhrase.read(SearchPhrase.java:28)
    at task.SearchPhrase.walk(SearchPhrase.java:16)
    at task.SearchPhrase.walk(SearchPhrase.java:14)
    at task.SearchPhrase.main(SearchPhrase.java:48)`

***Maybe is is another approach for solving this issue?***

Comment: Help us out a little here.  What are you expecting to happen, and what happened?

Comment: Please explain exactly and in detail what the problem is instead of just saying "I did some mistake". Does the program compile? If not, what error do you get? Does it run? Do you get an exception? If yes, then show the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing a couple of mistakes here..

```
[...]
  if (read(titleName.getName()).contains(whatFind)) {
                System.out.println("File: " + titleName.getAbsoluteFile());
      }
 [...]
```

In the above code you are passing the file name to the read method which is wrong. Instead you have to pass the filename along with its path like this...

```
    if (read(**titleName.getAbsolutePath()**).contains(whatFind)) {
                System.out.println("File: " + titleName.getAbsoluteFile());
     }
```

And there is no need of getAbsoluteFile() here

```
   [...]

       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(
                fileName).**getAbsoluteFile()**));
   [...]
```

Comment: **sampath**, thank you a lot!   All work now!

Comment: `System.out.println("File: " + titleName.getAbsoluteFile()) => + titleName.getAbsolutePath()`